# Using jquery to change a css value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was hoping to use jQuery to change two CSS values.
I need to resize a Youtube videos iframe width and height on the fly
then a user resizes the browser window.

Here is my code:

```
function resizeWP( width, height ) {
$( "#1" ).text( "RESIZING webpage" );

var layer_width = $( "#red" ).width();
var layer_height = $( "#red" ).height();
var string_width = layer_width.toString();
var string_height = layer_height.toString();
$("#2").text(string_width);
$("#3").text(string_height);

$("iframe").css({"width":"1250px","height":"800px"});
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
resizeWP();
});
```

I am almost there.
Just need some help getting over the top.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so why are you having all these vars if you're changing iframe width and height to fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("iframe").css({"width":"1250px","height":"800px"});` to `$("iframe").css({"width": layer_width + "px","height": layer_height + "px"});`.

However, it would be better to do this with CSS.

I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: I do this in CSS already, but if a visitor chooses to resize his browser the iframe the youtube video is in will show scrollbars. So I figured a dynamic change of the CSS values of width and height on the iframe will counter that. I know it might be a better solution, but I want to try this one out. It is a great way to learn more.

Anyway, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Tried to post a screenshot, but need 10 reputations first.

Trying imagehost:
http://imageshack.com/a/img855/8061/n735.jpg

Comment: When I changed the width and height of an IFRAME that contained an embedded YouTube video, the player scaled nicely. If you're just having a YouTube player on your page, use this: `iframe{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}`. Tell me if you need more help. I can't provide every option in my comment. :)

Comment: He he...

Did not think about that one: width: 100%; height: 100%;

Thanks... :)